# When Input change with JQuery function not take onchange Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i again...

I have a little problem with function save the price of the Quote system

I execute :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#GPrecio').blur(function () {
  $('[data-inputtype="Precio"]').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

for change all inputs of precio to take same price for all, but not take this function "changeprecio" when i change all inputs with 1st code:

```
$table.="<td>";
     $table.='<div onchange="changeprecio('.$idPedido.', this);">';
     $table.="<input type='text' value='".$PedidoPrecio."' size='3' name='Precio[]' id='Precio".$idPedido."' data-inputtype='Precio' onkeyup='sumar".$idPedido."()'></div></td>";
```

I need change the onchange call function ? for other ? onkeyup or other one ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following goes in the direction of what you are looking for. I faked the PHP table generation part via a small JavaScript snippet. I also removed the `onchange` attribute of your divs as they will not make any sense, unless your divs are to be editable.

I changed the event listening to `.on("input", ...)` as this will pick up any change of the input, be it by keyboard or mouse.

```js
$('#GPrecio').on("input",function () {
  $('[data-inputtype="Precio"]').val($(this).val());
});

$("table").eq(0).html([[1,3.4],[2,4.5],[5,7.1],[6,3.1],[8,2.5],[9,4.2],[12,3.7]].map(([idPedido,PedidoPrecio])=>
     `<tr><td><div>id ${idPedido}:<br>
      <input type="text" value="${PedidoPrecio}" size="3" name="Precio[]" id="Precio${idPedido}" data-inputtype="Precio"></div></td></tr>`).join("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="GPrecio" value="1.23">
<table></table>
```